# How to approach a rails complex nested model form (with Ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a newbie in Rails and am working on a page that enables users to create a question and add multiple options to it. (using ajax)

So the page needs to have a form that allows users to add a question title and that also has a button when clicked , it adds a text box to add a question option. The user can click on the "add" button multiple times and each times it needs to add a text box for the option. At the end the user will click on save and the question along with options will be saved.

So I have this model for question,

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type => String
  field :type, :type => String

  embeds_many :question_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_options
```

Now in my question view, I have displayed the form for question title and type. I am not sure how to go about building the form fields for question option because I think that everytime the user clicks on "add" button, I need to call

```
@question.question_options.build
```

But is that trip to server neccessary? If yes, how do I know which question to call the build on as I haven't saved teh question yet. If not, what should be my approach.

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems I didn't look hard enough earlier. There is a very simple way to do nested forms now using this amazing gem from Ryan Bates called "nested_form" (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). Thanks @robin for your input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the `@question.question_options.build` the first time you load the page, so that you'll have one "question_option" field.

Then, when users click the "add" button, I think that all you have to do is duplicate the first "question_option" field using javascript.

Not sure my explanation is clear on this one. Tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: That helped. Also I found a plugin for the same https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form